A problem related to spectrum and C$^*$-algebra
Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator of the form $S\oplus T$ with respect to the decomposition $H\oplus H'$. The spectrum of $A$, $\sigma(a)$ is given by $\sigma(A)=\sigma(S)\cup \sigma(T)$. Suppose that $\sigma(S)\cap \sigma(T)=\emptyset$. With this setting, it is easy to see that the indicator function $\chi_{\sigma(S)}$ is continuous on $\sigma(A)$, i.e., $\chi_{\sigma(S)}\in C(\sigma(A))$. My question is what operator does $\chi_{\sigma(S)}$ represents in the $C^*$-algebra generated by $A$ and the identity $I$? I believe that $\chi_{\sigma(S)}$ represents the projection on $H$. However, I cannot prove it directly. Any hint will be appreciated.

Let $E$ and $F$ denote the spectral decomposition of $S$ and $T$, respectively. Then it is easy to check that $E\oplus F$ is the (unique) spectral decomposition of $A$. Hence
$$ \chi_{\sigma(S)}(A)=\chi_{\sigma(S)}(S)\oplus\chi_{\sigma(S)}(T)=1_H\oplus 0, $$
which is the orthogonal projection onto $H$.

Thank you! How would you prove uniqueness? Is it easy?

The uniqueness of the spectral decomposition is part of the spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators (see, for example, Theorem 12.23 of Rudin's Functional Analysis).
